# Receiving money on PayPal in Croatia?

Tags: ecommerce, paypal, croatia

I can send money with PayPal from Croatia, but can't receive it.  Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 3):

1. Can you open a bank account in another country?
2. Do you have anyone you trust who would be willing to send the money to you?
3. Can you deposit USD checks? If so, you could have Paypal send a check to a US address (again you'd probably need a friend).

Answer (score 1):

The workaround that I use in a recent time is very simple, effective and it is spreading very quickly - Payoneer.

What you will need is http://www.payoneer.com/USPService.aspx which will get you US bank account that you can link to your paypal account.